How do I pre-compile an EF Core 9 model/queries spread across multiple projects?
I currently have an app using EF Core with the database functions spread across several projects:

Data Model project, containing all model objects that will be found in the database
DbContext project, containing the context and model configuration
Migrations project.
Factory project, responsible for instantiating a DbContext with the appropriate provider / file IO / migration options
Application service project, which grabs an instance from the factory project and presents methods to the app for retrieving specific query results

With the release of EF Core 9, I'd like to precompile the model and queries with Native AOT, to hopefully boost performance on Android.
However I'm struggling to figure out where to do things and how to get the tools to co-operate.
I initially tried pre-compiling the model/queries in the service project, but that failed with numerous missing namespace issues.  I came to the conclusion that was a doomed endeavor anyway, as the Service project doesn't instantiate the DbContext and so has no way to specify the compiled model to use.
I felt I couldn't pre-compile the model in the DbContext project, as it lacks access to the Migrations due to circular references, and so attempted to make a new project (with an IDesignContextFactory) specifically for housing the compiled model.  However attempts to generate the model with the CLI tools are failing with an NRE (see below).
dotnet ef dbcontext optimize --configuration Release --context FieldStorageContext --nativeaot
Build started...
Build succeeded.

NativeAOT support is experimental and can change in the future.
Your target project 'FieldStorageCompiledModel' doesn't match the assembly containing 'FieldStorageContext' - 'FieldStorage'. This is not recommended as it will cause the compiled model to not be discovered automatically.

Consider changing your target project to the DbContext project by using the Package Manager Console's Default project drop-down list, by executing "dotnet ef" from the directory containing the DbContext project or by supplying it with the '--project' option.


System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqToCSharpSyntaxTranslator.GetUnsafeAccessorName(MemberInfo member)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpRuntimeModelCodeGenerator.RegisterPrivateAccessor(IPropertyBase property, Boolean forMaterialization, Boolean forSet, String namespace, BidirectionalDictionary2 unsafeAccessorClassNames, Dictionary2 unsafeAccessorTypes, Dictionary2& memberAccessReplacements) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpRuntimeModelCodeGenerator.RegisterPrivateAccessors(IPropertyBase property, String namespace, BidirectionalDictionary2 unsafeAccessorClassNames, Dictionary2 unsafeAccessorTypes, Dictionary2 memberAccessReplacements)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpRuntimeModelCodeGenerator.GenerateModel(IModel model, CompiledModelCodeGenerationOptions options)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CompiledModelScaffolder.ScaffoldModel(IModel model, String outputDir, CompiledModelCodeGenerationOptions options)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.ScaffoldCompiledModel(String outputDir, String modelNamespace, DbContext context, String suffix, Boolean nativeAot, IServiceProvider services, ISet1 generatedFileNames) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.Optimize(String outputDir, String modelNamespace, String suffix, Boolean scaffoldModel, Boolean precompileQueries, DbContext context, Boolean optimizeAllInAssembly, Boolean nativeAot, List1 generatedFiles, HashSet1 generatedFileNames) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.Optimize(String outputDir, String modelNamespace, String contextTypeName, String suffix, Boolean scaffoldModel, Boolean precompileQueries, Boolean nativeAot) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OptimizeContextImpl(String outputDir, String modelNamespace, String contextType, String suffix, Boolean scaffoldModel, Boolean precompileQueries, Boolean nativeAot) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OptimizeContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_01.b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)

I can't figure out if this is because what I'm trying to do is unsupported, because I'm getting some setting wrong, or because there's a bug with the nativeaot implementation (it is experimental after all). I can generate a model without nativeaot, but as far as I can tell I won't be able to generate pre-compiled queries in the future without it, and at any rate getting it working would be ideal regardless. I'm also hazy as to whether the tools can currently pre-compile queries and generate interceptors using a model generated somewhere else.

A NullReferenceException in the middle of a stack trace that don't belong to you smells like a bug in the stack frame in question, ie: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqToCSharpSyntaxTranslator.GetUnsafeAccessorName you should report this here https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues

That's what I figured, but the documentation is sparse for the new feature and I couldn't be sure I wasn't missing something or combining mutually exclusive options.  An NRE is bad news anyway, so even if I ultimately could avoid it I should probably still let them know.  I'll work on getting a minimal reproduction together.

An attempt to create a minimal reproduction has failed, with the tools generating a model without complaint.  So it would appear there's something specific to this App's model that triggers the problem, where the standard tutorial Blog/Post model doesn't.

Note that their release notes about the pre-compilation is not production ready, it's effectively a proof of concept. Expect it to be buttoned down (or abandoned if there are serious obstacles) in EF 10.

Figured it out.  If the name of a backing field to a navigation collection doesn't match the corresponding collection's name optimize breaks.  See https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/35219#issuecomment-2505210098
